# LINQ2SQL : Auto-Sync=OnInsert

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a column named CreationDate for which I set 
Auto Generated Value = true
Auto-Sync=OnInsert
It is working perfectly well however I still wondering why it is synchronized when I do an UPDATE
Here what SQL Server profiler shows when I update any column in this table

> exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE
>   [dbo].[T_Address]  SET [CountryCode] =
>   @p2  WHERE ([AddressGuid] =@p0) AND
>   ([ColVersion] = @p1)
>
> SELECT [t1].[CreationDate], 
>          [t1].[ColVersion], 
>           [t1].[LastActivityDate] FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [t1] WHERE
>   ((@@ROWCOUNT) > 0) AND
>   ([t1].[AddressId] = @p3)',N'@p0
>   uniqueidentifier,@p1 timestamp,@p2
>   char(2),@p3
>   uniqueidentifier',@p0='18CD7808-038C-DF11-9935-00214F54AE12',@p1=0x000000000000105D,@p2='DZ',@p3='18CD7808-038C-DF11-9935-00214F54AE12'

why my CreatationDate is returned by the second select?
Am I misundertanding the concept of **Auto-Sync=OnInsert**

Thnaks for your comments

Answer (score 2):

I believe Auto-Sync=OnInsert is correct, but you need to set **Auto Generated Value** to **False**. "Auto Generated Value" is rather poorly named; it actually applies more to SQL Server Calculated Columns (which can change based on anything) than to values defaulted on insertion.